# How to implement animation in remoteviews in notification layout in android lollipop?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-5.0-lollipop, android-notifications

In my custom notification panel I have to animate the image view with a series of images. Though Lollipop does not animate images when we call:

```
imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.download_app_animation);
```

So we have to animate images in lollipop like this:

```
ImageView imageview = (ImageView) indViewById(R.id.imageview1);

imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.download_app_animation);

((AnimationDrawable) imageview.getBackground()).start();
```

I had display the background image to remoteviews using this code:

```
RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);

remoteView .setInt(R.id.cus_notify_image, "setBackgroundResource", R.drawable.download_app_animation);
```

My question is I have to animate images in notification panel using RemoteViews. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?